# Deleting the original User model in Django

Tags: python, django

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding custom User models in Django. I get how we can make a custom User model by inheriting from AbstractBaseUser and it'll provide the core implementation of the User model, however, what I don't get is shouldn't the original auth_User table be deleted? When I make migrations, I notice that I get both an implementation of myapp_User and auth_user along with all the other auth tables.

Why is this? I thought we are overriding auth_User with our own implementation. Why does auth_User exist? Is there a purpose for it to exist?

Comment: it exists because you might have used custom usermodel after applying initial migration. try to remove all migration files and delete all tables from database and then apply migrations

Comment: @Gahan Yes, you're correct. That solved it. Thank you!